# Wich one is better to use when we ask an user to do it again or finish? In Java

Tags: java

We ask to the user if he wants to do it again or finish.
The thing is we let him put [Y] or [N] answer, but can be that he mistakes.
So my problem enters here...

Structure one

```
       //kb = keyboard 
       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
       //String for the [Y] or [N] answer
       String r = "";
       //boolean to go out the loop and finish
       boolean out = true;

       do {
       //rest of the code of the program
       some stuff
       //
       System.out.println("Do you want to do it again?\n"
                + "[Y] or [N]");
        r = kb.next();
       }while(r == "y" || r == "Y");
```

Structure two

```
       do {
       //rest of the code of the program
       some stuff
       //
       System.out.print("Do you want to do it again?\n"
                + "[Y] or [N]");
        String answer = kb.next();
        switch (answer)
        {
        case "Y": out = true;
             break;
        case "y": out = true;
             break;
        case "N": out = false;
             break;
        case "n": out = false;
             break;
        default :
             System.out.println("Not a valid option")   ;
             break;
        }//end switch
        }while(out);
```

And how I can do it better if the user answer with another word?

Comment: Hardly anybody programs "do it again?" questions after programming 101. Either the program keeps going (e.g., a text editor) and the user can just quit the program when he's done. Or the program always stops after one run (Unix commands like  `ls`) and the user can run it again if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a style question.  There's no exact right answer.

The switch is a lot more code, so I'd avoid that.
You can take care of the case issue with

```
 r = kb.next().toUpperCase();
```

and then use

```
while ( r.equals("Y") )
```

since r is a string.